# Where to find Documentation for developing QGIS Plugins?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, documentation

I thought I would try to write a plugin for QGIS (some Python code that I hoped I could easily port) I started following http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html but that turned out to be hopelessly out of date. I turned to http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html instead and started going through the intro for the Python console and stumbled at the second query.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
```

worked fine but then

```
layer.getLayerID()
```

threw up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'getLayerID'
```

and sure enough code completion in the console would seem to suggest that this doesn't exist. So my question is "where do I find up to date, usable instructions for developing plugins for QGIS 2.2?" It would seem that unless you are already "in the know" there is no way in. Or am I just being paranoid?

Answer (score 5):

The most complete API docs are located at http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html

A good Python-specific resource is [The PyQGIS Programmer's Guide](http://locatepress.com/ppg). It's new and written for the 2.x API.

Concerning the pyQGIS Cookbook: I assume you are referring to the screenshot on http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html? This seems to have slipped through when the documentation was updated. That can happen. If you find documentation issues, it would be extremely helpful if you report them on the [QGIS Documentation Github page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation).

Comment: Any idea when the newbie intro will be updated? Ploughing through the API each time the old intro bowls a googly doesn't appeal at the moment (in the middle of writing PhD thesis and need less, not more stress).

Comment: Try http://locatepress.com/ppg

Comment: All documentation resources are continually updated - mostly by volunteers. You can support their efforts by letting them know if you spot certain issues.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the Underdark's list I like those :

- Joel Lawhead, 2015. Qgis python programming cookbook. Packt Publishing, p 340.
- Erik Westra, 2014. Building Mapping Applications with QGIS. Packt Publishing, p 150.
- Anita Graser, 2014. Learning Qgis. Packt Publishing, p 150. ;)